# What does "intrinsic" implementation mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When browsing through Kotlin source code, I found that in some places `NotImplementedError` is thrown:

```kotlin
public suspend inline val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() {
        throw NotImplementedError("Implemented as intrinsic")
    }
```

```kotlin
public suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn(crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Any?): T {
    contract { callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE) }
    throw NotImplementedError("Implementation of suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn is intrinsic")
}
```

I assume these are not real not-implemented errors since otherwise code cannot run.

My questions are:

- what does "intrinsic" mean here and why `NotImplementedError` is thrown?
- where could I view the source code for these implementation?

Comment: is this function `suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn` from some library?

Comment: Pretty sure it means it's implemented directly in the compiler and doesn't have a sensible Kotlin source-code equivalent that it could show you. It's not something that you could write yourself in Kotlin.

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand, but I expect it means that the implementation is coming from somewhere else, e.g. hard-coded into the compiler or pulled in from some other Kotlin or native library — possibly selected from among multiple implementations. It may be related to [JVM intrinsics](/questions/19892322/when-will-jvm-use-intrinsics).

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [great answer](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-primitives-source-code/2469/8) for you, my dude.

Comment: Don't add just a link. Bring the content to your answer. Links can be broken\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).